# To manage user authentication on multiple website through SSO

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

- Created an account on Onelogin which act like Identity Provider (IDP)
- Created a connector app for the website 1
- Added onelogin SSO configuration for the website 1
- Added the onelogin auth in the website 1
- Added a link to the website 2 in the authenticated pages of the website 1
- After onelogin auth in website 1, I wanted to know what are the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add onelogin sso for website 2 as well, like what you did to website 1.